# Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type-REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to create a task in SalesForce using the code below:

```
    var uri = Uri + "/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Task/";
    CreateTask Task = new CreateTask();



     var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var body = ser.Serialize(Task);


    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Task);


    var request = (HttpWebRequest)(HttpWebRequest.Create(uri));

    request.ContentType = "application/json"; var req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + Token);
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    req.ContentLength = body.Length;
    var os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    os.Close();
    WebResponse resp;

    try
    {
        resp = req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        resp = ex.Response;
    }
```

Its breaking saying the Error `Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.`
I am not sure how to fix this, its working fine when I am trying to do a PATCH with the same code but with this its not

Comment: You are using 2 requests `req` and `request`. Just use one. You're only setting the method for one of the requests.

Comment: -_-  I spent 30 Min on this thanks! @haldo